# How does this small change crash my program?

Tags: haskell

EDIT FOR CLARITY:  I know what the 'head of empty list' error is and why it is thrown.  What I don't know is why there is no error when I use 'elem' but there is if I use 'mElem'.  That's the only change I make to cause the error.

If I use the 'Prelude.elem' function the program runs but with one small error. I wrote my version of 'elem' (mElem) to counter this error.  I looked at the source code for 'elem' and wrote my function in a similar style.  However, the program crashes due to a 'head of empty list error' resulting from the function 'getExisting'

```
genTupleCount :: [F.Record] -> [(String, Int)] -> [(String, Int)]
genTupleCount [] tuples = tuples
genTupleCount (x:xs) tuples | mElem (F.club x) (map fst tuples) = genTupleCount xs $ getNewTuples tuples existing
                            | otherwise = genTupleCount xs $ (F.club x, 1):tuples
                        where 
                            existing = getExisting x tuples

getExisting :: F.Record -> [(String, Int)] -> (String, Int)                         
getExisting x tuples = head $ filter ((==F.club x).fst) tuples

getNewTuples :: [(String, Int)] -> (String, Int) -> [(String, Int)]
getNewTuples old e = (fst e, 1 + (snd e)):(delete e old)

mElem :: String -> [String] -> Bool
mElem _ [] = False
mElem str (x:xs) = (map toLower str) == (map toLower x) || mElem str xs
```

Comment: If I use elem then no error occurs, but if I change it to mElem then the error that Matt has explained occurs.

Comment: elem never returned True, but mElem did apparently, so getExisting  eventually got evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Matt Fenwick said, you're assuming there is an element that satisfies your condition. I suggest using `find` instead:

```
getExisting :: F.Record -> [(String, Int)] -> Maybe (String, Int)
getExisting x = find ((==F.club x).fst)
```

This handles the case of there not being any such element by returning `Nothing`, and let's you skip `mElem` entirely; just check the result of `getExisting` to find out whether there is any such element, and if there is, what its value is.

As to why using `mElem` instead of `elem` causes your program to crash, it is because it does *not* verify that there is an element that satisfies the condition `getExisting` searches for. `getExisting` doesn't normalise the capitalisation as `mElem` does, so if `nElem` returns True only because of its case-folding, then the call to `getExisting` will occur, and it will perform `head` on the empty list, because `filter` will find no elements matching `getExisting`'s stricter condition.

The `find` solution avoids this potential for error, since it only has the condition in one place.

Comment: As I said to Matt, I know that this my error.  I asked WHY using mElem instead of elem brings about this error.

Comment: I am not debating that different code shouldn't lead to a different result, I was simply wondering why it did in this instance since I tried to model my code on the source of elem.  Ehird has answered the question

Answer (score 1):

Your function `getExisting` assumes that the result of `filter ((==F.club x).fst) tuples` has at least one element.

Example:

```
Prelude> head [3,4]
3
Prelude> head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

It looks like switching to `mElem` causes an empty list to eventually be passed to `head`.  Apparently, this doesn't happen using `elem`.

Comment: Yes I know that, I stated that the error came about for this reason.  But how does the change in the 'elem' function bring about this error?

Comment: @Aurora -- could you clarify what the 'change' in `elem` is?  That's not clear in the OP.  My guess is that using `mElem` causes an empty list to eventually be passed to `head`.